# Transmitting live video over long distances with ethernet?

Tags: camera, hdmi, ethernet, streaming-video

I'm having trouble thinking of the best way to transmit live video using a pi zero w and a camera module through a wired ethernet connection of around 100ft. (model 3 could also be used) I want to overlay a couple sensor readouts like temperature and humidity onto the footage and some control using possibly rs485 or another protocol through ethernet would be great for changing camera angle using a servo with a joystick on the other end. (RS485 uses 2 wires)

HDMI to ethernet exists, however 
Is there a solution which does not use all 8 wires of the ethernet cable? 
Would there be a problem with interference between both signals? I am not sure how twisted pairs work with cancelling emf in an ethernet cable.

Ethernet cable is desirable for its cheap cost/ft!

Comment: Have you looked into HDMI-to-CAT5 converters?

Comment: I've taken a look at hdmi to ethernet converters, some require 2 ethernet cables which is where I turned away from them but on researching some more it seems that there exists converters with only one ethernet cable.

Answer (score 3):

There are great HDMI-over-CAT6 cables.

Some use 2 cables and can go up to 300 feeet.

Others use two cables and go 100 Meters.

Then there are also single-cable adapters that actually go 300 feet over a single cable, supporting 1080p and audio.

Here is the search I used:  [HDMI to Ethernet converter single cable](https://www.google.com/search?q=hdmi%20to%20ethernet%20converter%20single%20cable)

So there's your answer.  They are quite available, and affordable.

Whatever your software can generate to the HDMI port can run a large-screen at the 100 Ft specified.